# Assembly NASM x64 JMP not working as intended

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I have the following code:

```
section .data
    array times 1024 DW 0
section .text
    global _start
_start:
    mov ecx, array      ; Store the ponter to the first array element
    ; ---- ADD ----
    add dword [ecx], 8
label_1:
    cmp dword [ecx], 0
    je label_6
    ; ---- P UP ----
    add ecx, 2
    ; ---- ADD ----
    add dword [ecx], 15
    ; ---- p DOWN ----
    sub ecx, 2
    ; ---- SUB ----
    sub dword [ecx], 1
label_6:    ; ---- P UP ----
    add ecx, 2
    mov eax, 4 ; stdout
    mov ebx, 1 ; sys_write
    mov edx, 1 ; Lenth
    int 0x80      ; Call karnel    
    mov eax, 1       ; system call number (sys_exit)
    int 0x80        ;call kernel
```

It prints a char, but when I add `jmp label_1` one line above `label_6` it doesn't print anything. It is supposed to print the char `x` (8 * 15 = 120). Is something changing `ecx`?

Comment: The `add ecx, 2` is suspicious .. you know that a dword is 4 bytes, right? I assume you want 4 there.

Comment: Your title says x64, but you're using 32-bit pointers and 32-bit Linux int 0x80 system calls.  Also, "x64" is usually a Microsoft term; other people normally use the actual name of the ISA, x86-64 or amd64.

Comment: Also, `mov eax, 4 ; stdout` is fortunately just a buggy comment.  That's `__NR_write` for the 32-bit x86 ABI, and that's the right register for it.  If you had put `STDOUT_FD` into EAX, that would be the call number for `_exit`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your memory accesses are overlapping: a `dword` is 4 bytes, but you are doing `add ecx, 2` and `sub ecx, 2`. This means that your second `dword` is overlapping with the first one.

Your counter is stored at `array[0..3]`, and is treated as a `dword`. When you do `add ecx, 2; add dword [ecx], 15` you are touching `array[2..5]`, modifying the upper two bytes of your counter, which goes from `0x00000008` to `0x000f0008`. Your code will therefore pretty much run in an endless loop if you keep doing this.

Update your offsets to be `4` and your code should work:

```
    ...
label_1:
    cmp dword [ecx], 0
    je label_6
    ; ---- P UP ----
    add ecx, 4
    ; ---- ADD ----
    add dword [ecx], 15
    ; ---- p DOWN ----
    sub ecx, 4
    ; ---- SUB ----
    sub dword [ecx], 1
    jmp label_1
label_6:    ; ---- P UP ----
    add ecx, 4
    ...
```

---

Side notes:

- You don't need `cmp dword [ecx], 0` as the `sub dword [ecx], 1` already sets the zero flag, which is checked by `je label_6`. The previous `add dword [ecx], 8` sets ZF=0 so no problem.
- Your final `exit` syscall is exiting with a bad return code, you probably want `xor ebx, ebx` before `int 0x80` to exit with code `0`.